# In angular 2+, unable to capture data coming in the response of HttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular4-httpclient

I have a URL to hit, say http://172.22.xx.xx:port/domain/section. I am using HttpClient to make the http call and able to see 200 status code in the network tab of developers tool along with the json data.

**Component -**

```
this.coreService.getData().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.clear();
        console.log('res: ', data);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.clear();
        console.log('err: ', error);
      }
    );
```

**Service -**

```
getData() {
    const url = 'http://172.22.xx.xx:8080/domain/section';
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
```

The issue is, what I am able to capture is not the data coming in the response, but the error which is of **HttpErrorResponse** format.

[image]

And the response is in this format:

[image]

Want to know where this is going wrong? Is the data coming from the API in incorrect format?

Comment: It looks like you have missed '//' from your url

Comment: added '//' in const url now.

Answer (score 0):

In service try to get response this way.

```
getData() {
    const url = 'http://172.22.xx.xx:8080/domain/section';
    return this.http.get(url).map(response => response.json()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set headers to enable the json format

```
let headersConfig = {
   'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   'Accept': 'application/json'
};
let headers = new Headers(headersConfig)

this.http.get(url, headers );
```

Comment: This is what request headers  look like without setting the headers to enable json format.

GET <not showing due to privacy>
Host: <not showing due to privacy>
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HttpClient do like this :

Add **observe : 'response'** in header options of http.get method and subscribe to get response and error as well..

**Solution for your  query :**

**Component.ts**

```
this.coreService.getData().subscribe(
      res => {
        console.clear();
        console.log("Response",res);
        //if you to get response in variable then do 
         this.responsedata = res.body;
      },
      err => {
        console.clear();
        console.log('err: ', err);
      }
    );
```

**Service**

```
getData() {
    const url = 'http://172.22.xx.xx:8080/domain/section';
    return this.http.get(url,{observe: 'response'});
  }
```

**Handle Error Globally**

```
public errorHandler(err: HttpErrorResponse) : Observable<any>
  {
    if (err.error instanceof Error)
    {
      console.error("Client-side error occured.",err.status,err.error.message);
    }
    else 
    {
      console.error("Server-side error occured.",err.status,err.error.message);  
    }

    return ErrorObservable.throw(err || 'ERROR'); //throws error
  }
```